# (q/kdb+) Merge items in a list

Tags: kdb

I have a list of items and need to merge them into a single column

using the list

```
list:(1 2;3 4 5 7;0 1 3)

index   value
0       1 2
1       3 4 5 7
2       0 1 3
```

my goal is

```
select from list2

value
1
2
3
4
5
7
0
1
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted your list to appear like that I would do the following.

```
1 cut raze list
```

I see that you have used a select statement, however if you want your column defined as this in your table do the following

```
a:raze list
tab:([] b:a)
```

Your output from this should look like this

```
q)tab
b
-
1
2
3
4
5
7
0
1
3
```

Overall, a more concise way to achieve what you want to do would be

```
select from ([]raze list)
```

To avoid any errors you should not call the column header 'value' as this is a protected keyword in kdb+ and when you try to reassign it as a column header kdb will through an assign error

```
`assign
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that '1 cut' will change each item to list. So output will be list of lists and not list of integers. That might impact your other operations.

Answer (score 2):

'raze' function flattens out 1 level of the list.

```
   q) raze (1 2;3 4 5 7;0 1 3)
   q) 1 2 3 4 5 7 0 1 3
```

If you have list with multi level indexing then use 'over' adverb with raze:

```
   q)  (raze/)(1 2 3;(11 12;33 44);5 6)
```

To convert that to table column:

```
   q) t:([]c:raze list)
```

Answer (score 2):

`ungroup` would also work provided your table doesn't have multiple columns with different nesting (or strings)

```
q)ungroup ([]list)
list
----
1
2
3
4
5
7
0
1
3
```